# Schedule repeating event Akka

Tags: scala, akka, scheduler

In an Akka application one can schedule an Actor to do something repeated in the future using `context.system.scheduler.schedule` and then passing an `initialDelay` and then an `interval`.  I would like the interval to be random (i.e., draw from say an exponential distribution in the event I wished to model a poisson process).

How can I schedule an event to occur at random points in the future using the Akka Scheduler?

Comment: Would you like to change the interval after every scheduled job execution?

Comment: You should probably `scheduleOnce` with the new delay each time you are receiving it

Comment: Or create another sender actor

Comment: @EndeNeu Indeed. I want the interval to change after every execution.  I was hoping that you could pass the interval as a call by name parameter, but alas not.

Comment: No, instead you should `scheduleOnce` and once the tick happens, scheduleOnce with a randomly picked one again. The reason not to allow a call-by-name there is to not run into race conditions when this value would be evaluated (and perhaps mutating some state etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to be able to adjust the interval in the scheduler, that's not possible because of course that is immutable, but you can schedule the same job multiple times using `scheduleOnce` and adjusting the delay as you go:

```
case object DoSomething

class MyActor() extends Actor {
  var delay = 10

  context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay seconds, self, DoSomething)

  def receive: Receive = {
    case DoSomething =>
      doSomething()
  }

  def doSomething(): Unit = {
    /** do something */
    delay = delay * 2
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay seconds, self, DoSomething)
    ()
  }
}
```

You can schedule once the process and it will trigger the `doSomething()` method which will queue another scheduled job with a different delay.

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished with a recursive function:

```
def doSomething : Unit = ???

def randomIntervalGenerator : FiniteDuration = ???

@scala.annotation.tailrec
def randomSchedule(count : Int) : Unit = 
  if(count > 0) {
    Thread sleep randomIntervalGenerator.toMillis
    doSomething
    randomSchedule(count -1)
  }
```

Comment: Probably not as I would want the events to continue to be schedule indefinitely (or at least I don't know how a priori what `count` would equal).

Comment: Surely that would lead to an infinite recursion and cause the application to crash?

Comment: Not at all.  The tailrec annotation instructs the compiler to confirm that the recursion is optimized, therefore it does not continuously build up the call stack.  A tail-recursive function is equivalent to a while loop.  https://xkcd.com/1270/